# Is there a word that encompasses "chart" and "table"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to think of a name for the heading in a document where I am talking about charts and tables. Is there a concise, collective name for charts and tables I could use?

Comment: Directly below is best.  In the US "graphics" is immediately understood.  More particular are photo, drawing, table, graph.  I go with info-graphic if it is necessary to exclude (which I don't think it really does) all but tables and graphs.

Comment: Is a 'chart' a picture (like a bar chart)? 'Figure' might work for both.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the other suggestions offered, let me put forth some words that serve this purpose in various US environments.

When assigning students a project in which they need to present tables and charts in addition to (brilliantly written) text, I will ask for ***visuals*** generically, and will be given just what I seek.

Quoth M-W:

> something (as a graphic) that appeals to the sight and is used for effect or illustration —usually used in plural

As an author of a textbook that includes charts, graphs and similar illustrations, I will talk to my publisher about ***figures*** and be understood perfectly, the context having eliminated any confusion between numbers and their depiction.

This usage for ***figure*** doesn't show up in a cursory look at M-W's online dictionary, although it certainly does in the monstrous dead-tree edition. Instead, look to the [TEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276795/how-to-change-figure-1-to-bold-fig-1-in-latex) community in SE to see that these charts and tables and things are indeed called ***figures***, usually abbreviated as ***Fig.***

While I won't quarrel with ***visualisation***, especially at a couple of oceans' distance, and although I will grudgingly allow ***infographic*** as a comprehensible term despite its *portmanteau* neologism, I like these more generic terms better.

Comment: _Figures_ seems like the right answer here.

Comment: portmanteau neologism - well there's two words I am going to have to look up :)

Answer (score 2):

"Infographic" is a word which means a display of information, and can apply to both a table or a graph equally.

Infographic: [noun] A visual representation of information or data, e.g. as a chart or diagram.

Answer (score 1):

[Visualisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visualization_(computer_graphics)) comes to mind.

In computing, [data visualisation](http://searchbusinessanalytics.techtarget.com/definition/data-visualization) means

> displaying data in more sophisticated ways such as infographics, dials
>   and gauges, geographic maps, sparklines, heat maps, and detailed bar,
>   pie and fever charts.

Answer (score 0):

The word ***[statistics](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statistic)*** could be used.

> a collection of quantitative data

[Merriam-Webster]

You could precede *Statistics* depending on what data you're representing. (For example, *User Statistics*, *Site View Statistics*, etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure I would equate *statistics* - the numbers - with the charts and tables and so forth that have been used to represent them.  It's a fine distinction, perhaps, but one that resonates almost instantaneously to my NE US sense of the language.